# Binomial Coefficient Question

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

In the expression
$((. . . ((x − 2)^2 − 2)^2 − 2)^2 − · · · − 2)^2 − 2)^2$
,
there are $k$ pairs of parentheses, where k is a positive integer. In terms of $k$, find the coefficient of $x^2$
after expanding and collecting the terms

So far I have attempted to look for a recursion which would allow me to solve the problem. However, I cannot seem to find a relationship between the input of $k$ and the coefficient of the $x^2$ term. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you evaluated the value of the coefficient of $x^2$ for small $k$ (i.e. $k=1,2,3$...)?

Comment: Of specifically $x^2$?  Try to build a recursive sequence from inside out and recognize that by adding an additional $(~\underline{~~~~~~}-2)^2$ the new coefficient of $x^2$ will have to do with the previous coefficients of $x^2,x$ and $1$.

Comment: I did find that the first few coefficients are $1, 8, 24, 336, 5440,...$. However, I need to prove my result for $k$.

Comment: @mathcounter you mean these are the coefficients for $k=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$?

Comment: for k=2 I got 20

Comment: @V.Chen Indeed, I also find $20$. Wolfram says $336$ for $k=3$  and 6784 for $k=4$.

Comment: Sorry about that calculation error, you are both correct

Comment: First comment here should be this: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  This question, as it stands, it is nothing at all except a PSQ: Problem-statement-(question?), which looks it was merely transcribed verbatim from a problem assigned to ***you***.

Comment: PLEASE NO SHARING WOOT MATERIAL ONLINE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Let $F_k(x)$ the the function at the $k$-th step, then 
$$F_k(x)=a_kx^2+b_kx+4+o(x^2)$$
Then $F_1=x^2-4x+4$ implies that $a_1=1$ and $b_1=-4$.
Moreover
\begin{align*}a_{k+1}x^2+b_{k+1}x+4+o(x^2)&=F_{k+1}(x)=(F_k(x)-2)^2\\
&=(a_kx^2+b_kx+4+o(x^2)-2)^2\\
&=(4a_k+b_k^2)x^2+4b_kx+4+o(x^2).
\end{align*}
Therefore $b_{k+1}=4b_k=-4^{k+1}$ and 
$$a_{k+1}=4a_k+b_k^2=4a_k+16^k.$$
It remains to solve the linear recurrence for $a_k$.

Comment: I agree with your work up to this point, but how does this solve for the $x^2$ coefficient in terms of $k$?

Comment: @mathcounter Now solve the recurrences and find  $b_k$ and $a_k$.

Comment: Thanks, I have it now